# how to add a txt file into database table in netbeans

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to add some data's into a table in netbeans. i have the values in .txt and .xls format. is there any way to insert it into the table.?
i found this link to do the work.
[Link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/external-tables-9i.php)
but it showed an error when i performed this code

```
Create or Replace Directory cre_dir as 'C:\Users\Srinivasan\Desktop\SQL';
```

Error

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "OR" at line 1, column 8.
```

what is the mistake am i making here..?

Comment: Did you grant the `create directory` privilege to the user you are using?

Comment: no i didnt grant any

Comment: You can't have a hyphen in an object name (unless you use quoted identifiers, but don't do that); the actual directory has to be on the database server, it can't be on a client PC (not clear if it's the same box); and which client are you running the `create` command from, also from NetBeans?

Comment: from netbeans,  on my personal laptop..!

Comment: sorry.. i wrongly typed as '-'. its '_'

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to grant the `CREATE DIRECTORY` privilege to the user you are using or the user has to have `DBA` privilege
2. The path you are specifying must exists.

Read more about directories [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_create_directory.htm)

Comment: i still cant find the solution. In netbeans my UserName - **Maps** PW - **Maps**.